# vuex проблема с обновлением хранилища

Tags: vue.js, vuex

При загрузке приложения подгружаются по api нужные данные. Далее я редактирую изменения, и через axios отправляю и обновляю текущее состояние.

Если открыть вкладку разработчика во vuex, то видно, что данные обновлены. Однако, до тех пор пока я не совершу какое нибудь действие на сайте, при котором идет обращение к хранилищу, эти изменения не будет видно. Просто дайте направление что это может быть

Вот тут вся проблема:

```
const ORDER_UPDATED = (state, payload) => {
    state.items[payload[0]] = payload[1];
};
```

Если я не заменяю, а удаляю и вставляю, все работает:

```
const ORDER_UPDATED = (state, payload) => {
    state.items.splice(payload[0], 1, payload[1]);
    state.items.splice(payload[0], 0, payload[1]);
};
```

Все что придумал это вот этот костыль:

```
const ORDER_UPDATED = (state, payload) => {
    state.items[payload[0]] = payload[1];
    state.items.push();
    state.items.pop();
};
```

Comment: Ну так вы сейвите данные в базе. Но не обновляете стор, его нужно после обновления базы так же обновить по id

Comment: @RuslanSemenov в смысле не обновляю)) как иначе он у меня обновлен в инструментах разработчика))

Comment: А получаете как гетором?

Comment: @RuslanSemenov как то так - computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            orders: 'orders',
        }),

Comment: @RuslanSemenov у меня есть подозрения, что он не понимает, что было обновлено, там в структуре order есть emails -> items -> и тут уже что то обновляется, может для него это проблема

Comment: Нет он не отслеживает изменения объектов используйте `Vue.set(state.orders, payload[0], payload[1]);`

Comment: @RuslanSemenov благодарю, оказалось то, что нужно))))

Comment: Позанудствую )) Костыль вы придумали потому, что не читали документацию, где отлично описано как работать с массивами, чтобы реактивность работала как надо.

Comment: @yarkov_aleksei ну в мое оправдание, все же решилось в итоге)))))